# Murguu Auto Clicker in ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, shared-library

I got an error message when run [Murguu](http://www.murguu.com/) Auto Clicker x64 in ubuntu 16.04.1

```
$ ./AutoClicker
./AutoClicker: error while loading shared libraries: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

[Screenshoots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZcTB.png)

libxtst6 is installed, I check with this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxtst6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libxtst6 is already the newest version (2:1.2.2-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ locate libXts
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6.1.0
```

any ideas?

I hope there is someone can help to fix this

Thanks

Comment: link download Murguu x64 : http://www.murguu.com/linux-auto-mouse-click/download/64-bit/LinuxAutoMouseClick64Bit.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded [Murguu 64-bit zip file](http://www.murguu.com/linux-auto-mouse-click/download/64-bit/LinuxAutoMouseClick64Bit.zip) and later found out that `AutoClicker` file required 32 bit binary:

```
Liso@thinkpad:~/Downloads$ file AutoClicker 
AutoClicker: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=97621381fea36b46814d978e8ebab4f6caef9119, not stripped
```

So the issue seems to come from the 32-bit being of the required library, even though you install 64-bit version of Murguu.

Therefore you will need to install 32-bit version of `libxtst6`, it's quite easy:

```
sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386
```

Will do the jobs.

Comment: i got new error message after install libxtst6:i386


`./AutoClicker: error while loading shared libraries: libQxtGui.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
`

Comment: i can resolve with install `libqxt-gui0` and `libqxt-gui0:i386` use command `sudo apt-get install libqxt-gui0` and `sudo apt-get install libqxt-gui0:i386` . You're awesome @Liso, thanks.

Comment: Hm. Now by [link](http://www.murguu.com/linux-auto-mouse-click/download/64-bit/LinuxAutoMouseClick64Bit.zip) opens page, but not download.